# making a pattern by array variables

Tags: javascript

So I kind of understand that I need to use `for` loops, but i'm totally stuck.

Can someone help me by telling me which type of function I need to use?

[image: the basic should be like this, it won't be in terminal though, but normal javascript.]

```
// Variables
var myarray     = [3, 4, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3];
var pOutput = document.getElementById("pOutput");
pOutput.innerHTML = 

//Events
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
pOutput.innerHTML += "="}
n
//Functions
```

Comment: Look at the question you posted and ask yourself how anybody could possibly understand what you want to do and what problems you're having in your attempts to do it.

Comment: @Pointy sorry i thought i already wrote it.

Comment: @Shinji try to solve this problem first, if I give you a number 'n' can you print `n` `equal(=)` signs in a line ?

Comment: @ashishsingh yes i do, by
    var n = 3

    for (var i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
    pOutput.innerHTML += "=" 
    }

Comment: people have already answered , you can follow there

Comment: @ashishsingh thank you for trying to help as well. the problem u gave me was a good one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking to do is to print the equal sign times the number in each value of the array. To do that, I recommend you to use the repeat method from String prototype, like this:

```js
// Variables
var myarray = [3, 4, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3];
var pOutput = document.getElementById("pOutput");

// Fixed this too
pOutput.innerHTML = "";

//Events
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
    pOutput.innerHTML += "=".repeat(myarray[i])
}

// ...
```

Please, make sure to make a clearer question next time :)

Comment: Hello thank you so much. This totally worked. I knew I was starting on the right path, but unsure what to do next. I forgot I could use repeat method aha. Thanks again and I will make the question clearer next time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested loop to use the value of the current array element as the number of times to add `=`.

You're also not starting a new line and printing the line number first.

```js
// Variables
var myarray = [3, 4, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3];
var pOutput = document.getElementById("pOutput");

var output = "";


for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
  output += `<br>${i} : `;
  for (var j = 0; j < myarray[i]; j++) {
    output += "=";
  }
}

pOutput.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="pOutput"></div>
```

Comment: Oh my i wrote this earlier except the place where u wrote j < myarray[i] i wrote without [i] no wonder it didn't work. i'm such a newbie. thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
        const list = [3, 4, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3];
        const count = list.length;
        const result = [];
        const output = [];
        const dom = document.getElementById('output');

        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            const num = list[i];

            result[i] = [];

            for (let j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                result[i].push('=');
            }

            output[i] = `<div>${i} : ${result[i].join('')}</div>`;
        }

        dom.innerHTML = output.join('');
    </script>
</body>
```